# Counting multiple json inputs python

Tags: python, json, formatting

I get an input like this:

`input 1:`

```
{

"name": "Ben",
"description": "Ben",
"attributes": [
    {
    "type": "Background",
    "value": "Default"
    },
    {
    "type": "Hair-color",
    "value": "Brown"
    }
]
}
```

`input 2`

```
{

"name": "Ice",
"description": "Ice",
"attributes": [
    {
    "type": "Background",
    "value": "Green"
    },
    {
    "type": "Hair-color",
    "value": "White"
    }
]
}
```

`input 3`

```
{

"name": "Itay",
"description": "Itay",
"attributes": [
    {
    "type": "Background",
    "value": "Default"
    },
    {
    "type": "Hair-color",
    "value": "Brown"
    }
]
}
```

What I want to do is count the amount of each type of background and each type of hair-color appearing.
(These are sample examples and in reality there are more types and different values)

Let's say in these examples we have 2 objects that have a background as default then I want to have a count of that like so:

```
Backround default count=2
hair-color brown = 2
background green = 1
hair-color white = 1
```

I want the most effective code because there are other aspects to the code, in addition it will run on thousands of queries not just two, so needs to run in good times too :D
My code so far:

```
import requests
import json
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict
from time import sleep


attributes = []
test_dict = defaultdict(list)

for i in range(min_id, max_id+1):
    api = 'api/v1/test/{}'.format(i)
    response = requests.get(api)

    item_dict = json.loads(response.text)

    for item in item_dict['attributes']:
        attributes.append(item["trait_type"]) if item["trait_type"] not in attributes else attributes
        test_dict[item["trait_type"]].append(item["value"])
    sleep(0.02)

for attribute in attributes:
    print(attribute)
    print(Counter(test_dict[attribute]))
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to do it? How far did you get? What was the problem?

Comment: I get how i can count amount of times background, hair-color, default, brown, green and white has appeared.

I  don't get/know how to associate the background with default and green and hair-color with brown and white.

Comment: share your working code

Comment: @Sabil i don't have much working code, mainly the base of interacting with the API.

What I though on doing is creating a dictionary like so:
`{backround: default, count: 2}`
But that might complicate farther coding. In the end I want to calculate the amount of total objects (in our case 3) and divide each value by the total to see what % of the total values it is.

Comment: Did you try writing it so that you look at the `"type"` and `"value"` data *at the same time*, creating a single value out of them? Then you can write code that counts each appearance of a distinct type/value pair.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Posting my code that i got so far, idk how effective it is if effective.

Comment: I just update my answer, hope it resolves your all issues including ratio calculation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This should work for you:**

```
def constract_data(data_dict):
    output = []
    total_count = 0

    for data in data_dict:
        attributes = data["attributes"]
        for attribute in attributes:
            total_count += 1
            dict_key = attribute["type"].lower()
            dict_value = attribute["value"].lower()
            dict_index = [index for index, data in enumerate(output) if data.get(dict_key, "") == dict_value]

            if dict_index:
                output[dict_index[0]]['count'] += 1
            else:
                atb_dict = {dict_key: dict_value, 'count': 1}
                output.append(atb_dict)

    return output, total_count

def calculate_occurrence_ratio(data_dict, total_count):
    for index, data in enumerate(data_dict):
        count = data.get('count', 0)
        ratio = round(((count / total_count) * 100), 2)
        data['ratio'] = f'{ratio}%'

    return data_dict

data_dict = [
   {
      "name":"Ice",
      "description":"Ice",
      "attributes":[
         {
            "type":"Background",
            "value":"Green"
         },
         {
            "type":"Hair-color",
            "value":"White"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Ben",
      "description":"Ben",
      "attributes":[
         {
            "type":"Background",
            "value":"Default"
         },
         {
            "type":"Hair-color",
            "value":"Brown"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Itay",
      "description":"Itay",
      "attributes":[
         {
            "type":"Background",
            "value":"Default"
         },
         {
            "type":"Hair-color",
            "value":"Brown"
         }
      ]
   }
]

output_data, total_count = constract_data(data_dict)

output_data = calculate_occurrence_ratio(output_data, total_count)

print(output_data)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'background': 'green', 'count': 1, 'ratio': '16.67%'}, {'hair-color': 'white', 'count': 1, 'ratio': '16.67%'}, {'background': 'default', 'count': 2, 'ratio': '33.33%'}, {'hair-color': 'brown', 'count': 2, 'ratio': '33.33%'}]
```

Comment: What do you think an easier output to work with will be?
Yours or this:

`{'background': {'green': 1, 'default': 2}, 'hair-color': {'white': 1, 'brown': 2}}`

Comment: It depends on what will be your desire output?

Comment: In general what i want to do is give each trait a score.

Then if a user has a certain trait give it a score.
So in basically I want to calculate the rarity of each user occurring via a score.

Let's say the score for hair_color being white is 100, Ice will receive 100 points.

Comment: Ohh, then I have to update my answer match your requirements. :)

Comment: Ok amazing, ty and sorry for all the hustle :D Your answer is awesome tho and calculates everything perfectly. ty very much :D

Comment: If it resolved your issue then please accept my answer

Comment: Btw if i want to build a website for the app, do u suggest as a starter in web+python to do django, flask or what?

Comment: Output is still the same for me. atm it's only 3 users and 2 properties.
Real usecase will be around 5k-10k users and 5-10 properties each so it becomes quite un manageable, do you think my output (like i showed above) is better or yours for formatting and using it?

Comment: If you think that you may need to represent things in a dynamic way then you can continue with my output. If at some point you think that you need your formatted output then you can easily format that from my output. :)

Answer (score 1):

this solution will work for you:

```
list_data = [
{
"name": "Ice",
"description": "Ice",
"attributes": [
    {
    "type": "Background",
    "value": "Green"
    },
    {
    "type": "Hair-color",
    "value": "White"
    },
    {
    "type": "other",
    "value": "White"
    }
]
},
{

"name": "Ben",
"description": "Ben",
"attributes": [
    {
    "type": "Background",
    "value": "Default"
    },
    {
    "type": "Hair-color",
    "value": "Brown"
    }
]
},{

"name": "Itay",
"description": "Itay",
"attributes": [
    {
    "type": "Background",
    "value": "Default"
    },
    {
    "type": "Hair-color",
    "value": "Brown"
    }
]
},
]
output = {}
all_count = {}
for user in list_data:
    data = user["attributes"]
    for dat in data:
        typeu = dat["type"]
        if typeu not in all_count:
            all_count[typeu]=1
        else:
            all_count[typeu]+=1

for user in list_data:
    data = user["attributes"]
    for dat in data:
        typeu = dat["type"]
        if typeu not in output:
            output[typeu]={}
        if dat["value"] not in output[typeu]:
            output[typeu][dat["value"]] = "1 with: {}%".format(int(1/all_count[typeu]*100))
        else:
            count = int(output[typeu][dat["value"]][0])+1
            output[typeu][dat["value"]] = str(count)+" with: {}%".format(int(count/all_count[typeu]*100))
print(output)
```

Comment: Like i said in post tho, sometimes the attributes will not be just background and hair_color.

The script needs to identify them on his own...

Comment: okay i edited it

Comment: Do you think there is a way to also calculate the chance of it occurring?
So basically just divide the count of each item by total users:
`Backround default:2 
66% of it occuring`

Comment: i have edited it. can you please mark it as a solution?

Comment: When i put it in my code some attributes appear as 100% some not and the total % isn't 100%
example: `{'background': {'crisp green': '1 Ratio: 100%', 'dashing purple': '2 Ratio: 66%', 'spiffy blue': '1 Ratio: 25%', 'dapper cyan': '2 Ratio: 33%'}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data_dict = [
   {
      "name":"Ice",
      "description":"Ice",
      "attributes":[
         {
            "type":"Background",
            "value":"Green"
         },
         {
            "type":"Hair-color",
            "value":"White"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Ben",
      "description":"Ben",
      "attributes":[
         {
            "type":"Background",
            "value":"Default"
         },
         {
            "type":"Hair-color",
            "value":"Brown"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Itay",
      "description":"Itay",
      "attributes":[
         {
            "type":"Background",
            "value":"Default"
         },
         {
            "type":"Hair-color",
            "value":"Brown"
         }
      ]
   }
]

out = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
tot_count = defaultdict(int)
for data in data_dict:
    for attri in data['attributes']:
        tot_count[attri['type']]+=1
        out[attri['type']][attri['value']]+=1
for k, v in out.items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        print (f'{k.lower()} {k1} count={v1} ratio={int(v1*100/tot_count[k])}%')
```

Output:

```
background Green count=1 ratio=33%
background Default count=2 ratio=66%
hair-color White count=1 ratio=33%
hair-color Brown count=2 ratio=66%
```